# Result consisted of more than one row working on different server

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm newbie in stored proc, and I look for a solution since 3 weeks now... Someone can help me please? I'm using MySQL

Why it's working on my localhost (Windows wamp server), on my server hosted at pair.com but not on my ubuntu server

I get this error on my ubuntu server : « Result consisted of more than one row ». I've tried to insert 4 records and only the two first one are inserted...

Apache & MySQL version

- wamp : 2.4.9    --   5.6.17 (working)
- pair server : 2.2.31   --    5.1.56 (working)
- ubuntu : 2.4.7   --    5.5.43 (not working)

---

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `io_data_after_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `io_data_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `data_temp`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE idrad, idio_temp, idio_bat, idio_vac1, idio_vac2, idio_vac3 INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT IDRadio INTO idrad FROM radio WHERE radio.XB_SL=NEW.XB_SL;
SELECT ID_IO INTO idio_bat FROM io WHERE io.IDRadio=idrad AND NoIO=1;
SELECT ID_IO INTO idio_temp FROM io WHERE io.IDRadio=idrad AND NoIO=2;
SELECT ID_IO INTO idio_vac1 FROM io WHERE io.IDRadio=idrad AND NoIO=3;
SELECT ID_IO INTO idio_vac2 FROM io WHERE io.IDRadio=idrad AND NoIO=4;
SELECT ID_IO INTO idio_vac3 FROM io WHERE io.IDRadio=idrad AND NoIO=5;

IF NEW.Bat IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat IS NOT NULL AND idio_bat != 0 THEN 
INSERT INTO io_Data (ID_IO, ReadingValue, Timestamp) 
     VALUES (idio_bat, NEW.Bat, NEW.Timestamp);
END IF;
IF NEW.Temp IS NOT NULL AND idio_temp IS NOT NULL AND idio_temp != 0 THEN
INSERT INTO io_Data (ID_IO, ReadingValue, Timestamp) 
     VALUES (idio_temp, NEW.Temp, NEW.Timestamp);
END IF;
IF NEW.Vac_1 IS NOT NULL AND idio_vac1 IS NOT NULL AND idio_vac1 != 0 THEN
INSERT INTO io_Data (ID_IO, ReadingValue, Timestamp) 
     VALUES (idio_vac1, NEW.Vac_1, NEW.Timestamp);
END IF;
IF NEW.Vac_2 IS NOT NULL AND idio_vac2 IS NOT NULL AND idio_vac2 != 0 THEN
INSERT INTO io_Data (ID_IO, ReadingValue, Timestamp) 
     VALUES (idio_vac2, NEW.Vac_2, NEW.Timestamp);
END IF;
IF NEW.Vac_3 IS NOT NULL AND idio_vac3 IS NOT NULL AND idio_vac3 != 0 THEN
INSERT INTO io_Data (ID_IO, ReadingValue, Timestamp) 
     VALUES (idio_vac3, NEW.Vac_3, NEW.Timestamp);
END IF;

END
//DELIMITER ;
```

Also, I have to delete the data after it moved to the new table and I am not able . I read somewhere that I could not remove the lines used in a stored proc in the same stored proc. What is another way to clear the data that we just do?

Comment: Are your data sets *exactly* the same across all databases?  Manually run a `select count(*)` across your databases to see if there is only 1 row as you expect.

Comment: I have deleted all the files (php) and the database on my ubuntu server and now it seems to work. I have added "LIMIT 1" to make sure that I get one row only. By cons, I must make a few more tests with the automatic process which wasn't working before either... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome, but do you expect there to be only one?  Do you have inconsistencies if there are more than one match and you update the wrong row?

Comment: It's what I need to check. Now, I have removed the LIMIT 1, it's working, but I need to know what have caused the multiple rows... I'm in beta test for this program so, it's possible that was my test...

Comment: It's working using LIMIT 1... Thanks a lot!